# How do i make warping button using tailwind css v3 or vanilla css?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i want to ask how to make this button like this using tailwind css.

[image: button]

i tried making this button like this

```js
  <button
    className="bg-tory-blue-500 py-[18px] px-7 rounded-[20px]"
    style={{ boxShadow: "0px 2px 4px 0px #BFEAFF" }}
  >
    Start
  </button>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: check this like
[https://tailwindcss.com/docs/skew](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/skew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I tried, I had used two divs and skewed them, you can see both the divs by making the bg-color of them different.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-4">
  <div class="bg-blue-600 h-10 rounded-xl rounded-br-none absolute -skew-y-6 w-1/5 "></div>
  <div class="bg-blue-600 h-10 absolute rounded-xl rounded-tr-none skew-y-6 mt-5 w-1/5"></div>
 
<button
    class=" pt-[18px] px-7 bg-transparent ml-7 absolute top-3 text-white font-bold text-xl"
>
    Start
  </button>

  </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this help me, i just change rounded-xl to ronuded-full it seems similar

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-4">
  <div class="absolute h-10 w-28 -skew-y-6  rounded-tr-[20px] rounded-l-[20px] rounded-br-none bg-blue-600"></div>
  <div class="absolute top-2 mt-5 h-10 w-28 skew-y-6 rounded-l-[20px] rounded-br-[20px] rounded-tr-none bg-blue-600"></div>
  <button class="absolute left-9 top-7 bg-transparent text-xl font-bold text-white">Start</button>
</div>
```